# Sync node.js waterfall control flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

We are working on an app where let people borrow money. I have a node.js + mongodb logic where I really have no idea how to handle it.

the data model is like below for a list of user who willing to lend money to others (assuming there are only 3 lenders):

```
[
{
  _id:"100",
  amount:10.00
},
{
  _id:"101",
  amount:10.00
},
{
  _id:"102",
  amount:20.00
}
]
```

There is a user want to borrow, say $20.00 and hit submit. backend node.js will query mongodb perform the following logic:

**1. query mongodb by limiting 20 records**
code:

```
db.collection('post').find(
    {
        borrowed_date:{$exists:false}
    }).toArray(function(err, result) { 

    });
```

**2. loop thru the result and add up the amount until total match the amount of the borrower.**
**3. update mongodb for those matched record and finally result in database will be like below (borrow $20):**

[
{
  _id:"100",
  amount:10.00,
  borrowed_date:ISODate("2016-02-16T06:43:29.869Z")
},

{
  _id:"101",
  amount:10.00,
  borrowed_date:ISODate("2016-02-16T06:43:29.869Z")
},

{
  _id:"102",
  amount:10.00
}
]

code:

```
db.collection('post').update(
    {
        _id:100,
        borrowed_date:{$exists:false}
    }, 
    {$set:{borrowed_date:new Date()}}, 
    {w:1},
    function(err, result) {

    });
```

Above step I use async.waterfall to control. There will be no problem if the time between each borrower to hit the borrow button is like 10 seconds:

1. borrower1 borrow at 2016-02-16T06:00:00
2. borrower2 borrow at 2016-02-16T06:00:10
3. borrower2 borrow at 2016-02-16T06:00:20

if at a given time 2 borrowers borrow at the same second, it will be an issue. Assuming borrower1 is going to borrow $20 and borrower1 is going to borrow $10. 
So at Step1, both borrower1 will get 2 records with id 100 and 101. borrower2 will get 1 record with id 100 (where he should get id 102).

async.waterfall is async and will not wait until all the functions done then the 2nd request enter the waterfall loop.

Any idea how to handle this situation?

Comment: You need to break your question down into somthing much smaller. You are asking someone to solve your issues of concurrency, which are difficult.  As you say, you "really have no idea how to handle it" - perhaps go and do some further reading first.

Comment: Maybe a db transaction could help with this?  This really has no real relationship with your use of callbacks or w/e.

Comment: Could you outline why the recommended approach https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/ does not work in your case?

Answer (score 0):

use setImmediate will do to wrap all logic to get all posting hence it's one at a time

**

> Use setImmediate if you want to queue the function behind whatever I/O
>   event callbacks that are already in the event queue.

**

```
setImmediate(function searchPost() { 

   // all code here

});
```